# ¿Cómo hacer un ciclo que almacene datos para calcular un promedio?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Taller
{
      private:
          int c=0, d=0, x=0, y=0;
          float presion=0, masa=0, volumen=0, temperatura=0, sumaMoto=0, sumaVehi=0;
     public:
          void pedirDatos();
          float masaVehiculo(float, float, float);
          float masaMoto(float, float, float);

};

void Taller::pedirDatos()
{
   cout<< "¿Que masa desea calcular? Ingrese una de las opciones:  vehiculo = 1, moto = 2 "<< endl;
   cin >> x;

  if ( x==1)
    {
       c = 0;
       c = c+1;
      cout << "ingrese la presión del vehículo."<< endl;
      cin >> presion;
      cout <<  "ingrese el volumen del vehículo." << endl;
     cin >> volumen;
     cout << "ingrese la temperatura del vehículo." << endl;
      cin >> temperatura;

      float solucion=masaVehiculo (presion, volumen, temperatura);
    cout << "la masa de aire del vehículo es:" << solucion << endl;
    float sumaVehi=0;
    sumaVehi= sumaVehi+solucion;
    cout << "el promedio de masa de aire es:"<< sumaVehi/c << endl;


  }

    else
   {
       if (x == 2) {
        d=0;
        d=d+1;
        cout << "ingrese la presión de la moto." << endl;
    cin >> presion;
        cout << "ingrese el volumen de la moto." << endl;
        cin >> volumen;
        cout << "ingrese la temperatura de la moto." << endl;
        cin >> temperatura;
        float solucion=masaMoto(presion, volumen, temperatura);
        cout << " la masa de aire de la moto es:" << solucion << endl;
      float sumaMoto=0;
      sumaMoto=sumaMoto+solucion;
      cout << "el promedio de masa de aire de motos es:" << sumaMoto/d << endl;
      } else
      {
      cout << "a joder a su casa con otro numero mi apa" << endl;
      }
     
};


};

 float Taller::masaVehiculo( float pre, float vol, float temp)
 {
     float masa;
     masa= (pre*vol) / (0,37*(temp+460));
     return masa;
 };

float Taller::masaMoto( float pre , float vol , float temp)
 {
     float masa;
     masa= (pre*vol) / (0,37*(temp+460));
     return masa;
 };


int main ()
{
    Taller obj1;
    obj1.pedirDatos();
    }
```

Necesito que despues de ingresar los datos que el codigo pide, el codigo pregunte si quiere elegir de nuevo entre auto o moto, y que los datos que el usuario vaya ingresando cada vez que el ciclo se repite se guarden para que al final el codigo me regrese el promedio de todos los datos ingresados.
Necesito que despues de ingresar los datos que el codigo pide, el codigo pregunte si quiere elegir de nuevo entre auto o moto, y que los datos que el usuario vaya ingresando cada vez que el ciclo se repite se guarden para que al final el codigo me regrese el promedio de todos los datos ingresados

Answer (score 0):

Para almacenar datos, tendrás que guardarlos en algún sitio. Como por ejemplo un vector:

```
struct Cosa
{
    int tipo;
    float presion, volumen, temperatura;
};

std::vector<Cosa> cosas;
```

Para pedir datos hasta un límite, tendrás que decidir un código de finalización. Como por ejemplo cero:

```
for (int x = 0;;)
{
    cout<< "¿Que masa desea calcular? Ingrese una de las opciones: vehiculo = 1, moto = 2, finalizar = 0" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    if (!x) break;

    cout << "ingrese la presión del vehículo."<< endl;
    cin >> presion;
    cout <<  "ingrese el volumen del vehículo." << endl;
    cin >> volumen;
    cout << "ingrese la temperatura del vehículo." << endl;
    cin >> temperatura;

    cosas.push_back({x, presion, volumen, temperatura});
}
```

Para calcular el promedio, sumas todo y divides entre el número de datos.